# Remover espaço em branco Ionic 3

Tags: html, css, ionic, apache-cordova

Estou tentando remover esse espaço em branco do meu projeto. [image: errado]

Gostaria que ficasse assim: 
[image: certo]

```
 <ion-content no-padding>
<div [ngSwitch]="Menu" >
<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'Todosgastronomia'" >
    <ion-item  *ngFor="let produto of produtos" no-padding>
        <ion-thumbnail item-start no-padding>

        <img src="assets/imgs/mmsszjm.png" class="imgproduto">

        </ion-thumbnail>


        <h3 class="nomproduto"> {{produto.nom_produto}}  </h3>

        <h3 class="nomsubcategoria">{{produto.nom_subcategoria}} </h3>

        <h3 class="descproduto"> {{produto.desc_produto}}  </h3>

        <h3 class="valproduto">
           <font  color="#179c90">R$</font> {{produto.val_produto}}
        </h3>

        <button ion-button class="queroproduto">QUERO!</button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Eu quase consigo deixar um pouco igual, porém quando adiciono um botão, mesmo ele estando do lado direito >> "Botão QUERO!"  ele ocupa um espaço em branco do outro lado. Se alguém puder ajudar, Obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Se o que você precisa é que o botão "Quero" fique não fique abaixo do texto, tenho duas sugestões:

1- Incluir `item-end` no botão:

```
<button ion-button item-end class="queroproduto">QUERO!</button>
```

2 - Deixar o botão na mesma tag que o preço e alinhar à direita:

No arquivo .html:

```
<h3 class="valproduto">
    <font  color="#179c90">R$</font> {{produto.val_produto}}
    <button ion-button class="queroproduto">QUERO!</button>
</h3>
```

No arquivo .scss:

```
.queroproduto{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```